# Is this a good way to run code snippets sequentially?

Tags: javascript

```
<script src="./js/id.js"></script>
<script src="./js/fetch.js"></script>
<script src="./js/download.js"></script>
<script src="./js/playback.js"></script>
```

Each script is dependent on the former to finish.

Comment: Hard to say without seeing what exactly each file is doing. In general though, it isn't good practice to have code executing at the top level. It's much cleaner in most cases to have code in functions, then the importing code can manually call functions that they need.

Comment: No, absolutely not. Do as @Carcigenicate says. This is temporal coupling; execution is dependent on the order listed above, which virtually guarantees future bugs. Frist, this is easily re-arranged on purpose or not. Even purposeful re-arrangement will break it; who knows what the heck is in inside. It is totally non-obvious that these must be in any order at all. It requires very significant extra effort over time to keep working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this a good way [...]

**NO**, however it *will* work if the javascript inside is synchronous. The moment you decide to do something *asynchronous* (i.e.: `fetch.js` and `download.js` sound like they'll do something async) it won't work.

---

How about just wrapping and exposing an async function in each of your files.

For example, you could have your `fetch.js` having a wrapper function called `function myFetch(){ ... }` and your `download.js` having a wrapper function called `function myDownload(){ ... }` and then simply using `await` for each wrapper function you've exposed from every script file.

```js
// fetch.js file
function myFetch(){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("my Fetch Done");
      resolve("myFetch");
    }, 500);
  })
}

// download.js file
function myDownload(){
  return new Promise((resolve)=>{
    setTimeout(()=>{
      console.log("My download done");
      resolve("myDownload");
    }, 100);
  })
}

// main.js file

async function myMain(){
  // "synchronous"
  const res1 = await myFetch();
  const res2 = await myDownload();
  console.log('final log', res1, res2);
}

myMain();
```

Comment: This is what I had in the first place, but it didn't work. Looking at your code I understand I must include the async\await AND a promise inside the awaited function?

Comment: @Yigal yes your function should return a promise either by using `async` keyword or returning a `new Promise` inside the function itself.